# Opencart Recurring profile double charging

Tags: paypal, opencart, paypal-ipn, paypal-sandbox, opencart2.x

I am using a sandbox paypal account to test my express checkout with Opencart2's recurring profiles. I am getting the product one-time charge and the first recurring charge at the same time - effectively doubling the initial payment!  Is this because I am in sandbox mode and the IPN can not provide feedback? Or am I missing something.

Alternatively, how can I remove the price and just use the recurring profile price. For example. I would like to charge differently for the same product depending on the recurring profile, but I can't since the initial price is static (so I have been setting up multiple versions of the same product with a single recurring profile to match to account for this).

Thanks

Comment: Why not just get rid of the initial amount and create the profile by itself?  Then it charges the first day when the profile is created and you just get that one payment.  If you want to leave the initial amount then you would need to change the start date of the profile to be 1 term (month, year, or whatever) in the future instead of the same day.

Comment: Actually PayPal process this well, but OpeCart gives me this error once it sends me back to my page to confirm  "This transaction cannot be processed. The amount to be charged is zero."

Comment: Can you provide logs of the PayPal API requests?  It sounds like what may be happening is that OpenCart is calling both DoExpressCheckoutPayment and CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile to finalize the checkout when it should only be calling the latter.

Comment: This is still an issue in openCart.  I did use @robert-m work around but it is not pretty to have to go change the language files, which affects other products.  I believe Andrew is correct - the API is calling both when it should only be calling only the recurring in catalog/controller/extension/payment/pp_express.php

Answer (score 1):

You can enable a trial period for the recurring profile since the first term is included in the product price.

You will of course want to change the default language as it will confuse customers when they see...

> $0.00 every 1 month(s) for 1 payment(s) then $9.95 every 1 month(s)
>   until canceled

I usually remove the text before "$9.95"